# java null pointer exception when clicked on ImageView

Tags: android, onclick, nullpointerexception

Iam setting a share button for twitter to share a pic from my drawable later to be changed dynamically i got this code from the net and paste it in my app i got the following error null pointer exception and cant figure it out any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
enter code here

 ImageView twittersharing =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter_sharing);
    twittersharing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "On click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath("placeholder.jpg");
            share("com.twitter.android",filePath.toString());
        }
    });

      public void share(String nameApp, String imagePath) 
{
    try
    {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpg");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty())
        {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) 
            {
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpg"); // put here your mime type
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Photo");
                 targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This photo is created by ME");
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
                    targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),  "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,  targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
         Log.v("VM","Exception while sending image on" + nameApp + " "+  e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the picture using:
        twitterSharing.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);

Comment: Maybe try Cleaning the project to rebuild your R file. Project > clean

Comment: Could you give us the log errors you get? on what line does the nullpointer occur?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell where exactly it is giving NullPoitnerException?

Also, you do have that image mentioned here (placeholder.jpg) in your device, right?

```
File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath("placeholder.jpg");
share("com.twitter.android",filePath.toString());
```